# Get ALL or SPECIFIC data from the DB using multiple query parameters (ASP.NET Core Web Api)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext

I am working on an ASP.NET Core Web Api where I want to create a method that takes multiple parameters from the user, all of which are optional, and return the filtered data.

Something like:

```
public async Task<ReportEntity> GetReportByFilters(StatusEnum paramA, bool paramB, ReportStatusEnum paramC)
{
    report = await _context.tbl_Reports.Include(x => x.User)
                       .Where(x => x.Status == paramA, x.IsDone == paramB, x.ReportStatus == paramC)
                       .ToListAsync();
    return report;
}
```

These parameters could be parses or not in which case, the filter should be removed. In case of no params, all data should be received.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is something like that:

```
public async Task<ReportEntity> GetReportByFilters(StatusEnum? paramA, bool? paramB, ReportStatusEnum? paramC)
{
    var query = _context.tbl_Reports.AsNoTracking();

    if (paramA != null)
        query = query.Where(x => x.Status == paramA.Value);
    if (paramB != null)
        query = query.Where(x => x.IsDone == paramB.Value);
    if (paramC != null)
        query = query.Where(x => x.ReportStatus == paramC.Value);

    var report = await query.Include(x => x.User).ToListAsync();

    return report;
}
```

Comment: Assuming: you are using `LINQ`, so methods are returning `IQueryable<TSource>`

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, I'm unable to query on var query. `'System.Linq.IQueryable<XYZ.ReportEntity>' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<XYZ.ReportEntity, XYZ.AppUser>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` I get this error

Comment: Check the code now (`Include(x => x.User)` moved to last)

Comment: Why do I get this error: `System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32` This is when I am testing my API and I get this error with 500 Status Code

Comment: You have a circular reference in your objects. For example: `Report` references `User` and `User` references `Report` (to any other combination of other objects inside your `tbl_Reports` or `User`). You can use attributes like `[JsonIgnore]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @CicheR. Sorry, I am new to this whole thing. Could you please explain where and how do I need to use the above option? Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213747/discussion-between-mansi-and-cicher).

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WCqljGb.png  (was unable to chat today)